# ko.computed is not working with dynamically added properties

Tags: knockout.js

I wrote the code like below.

```
var ModalInit = function (serverModel, element) {
    var dailyReport = new DailyMasterReport();
    $.extend(true, dailyReport, ko.mapping.fromJS(serverModel));

    dailyReport.SelectAll = ko.computed({
        read: function () {

            var isAllSelected = true;
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(dailyReport.AvailablePods(), function (item) {
                isAllSelected = isAllSelected && item.PodAvailable
            });
            return isAllSelected;
        },
        write: function (newValue) {

            if (newValue) {
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(dailyReport.AvailablePods(), function (item) {
                    item.PodAvailable(true);
                });
            } else {
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(dailyReport.AvailablePods(), function (item) {
                    item.PodAvailable(false);
                });
            }
        },
        owner: DailyMasterReport
    });

    ko.applyBindings(dailyReport, $(element)[0]);
```

};

In this the above code , when I change the check box in available pods, then it is not updating the computed value.Here if I write the computed logic inside the viewModel, then it is giving the error.

Can any one provide the solution for this problem.

Comment: 'it is giving the error', What error ?

Comment: When we are creating the object, at that time the viewModel didn't have the "AvailablePods" property. Hence it is giving the error like '0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'AvailablePods''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PodAvailable` is an observable so you need to unwrap it in your `read` function:

```
    read: function () {
        var isAllSelected = true;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(dailyReport.AvailablePods(), function (item) {
            isAllSelected = isAllSelected && item.PodAvailable();
        });
        return isAllSelected;
    },
```

You might also be interested in improving this function, since it currently always checks every item for selection. But you really only need to know that one item is unselected to return `false`. For example, if every item is unselected, you only need to check the first one. Here's an updated version that's more efficient:

```
    read: function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(dailyReport.AvailablePods(), function (item) {
            return !item.PodAvailable();
        }) == null;
    },
```